# Can't delete files using SSHFS on windows

Tags: debian, files, windows, sshfs

My problem is that i can't delete any fails from any folder using my windows sshfs client. Even though i'm logging in through root account, it still says that i do not have enough permission to perform this action:

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it work from commandline (`sftp` or `ssh`) or from different client (WinSCP, FileZilla)?

Comment: Yes it even worked using samba, it's just something with sshfs

Comment: If it works with FileZilla, WinSCP and `sftp` (all using the same `sftp` as `sshfs`), then it is problem in Windows version of `sshfs` and therefore off-topic here.